# How to store output of array in csv using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, csv

sample json data file

```
{
  "Includes": {
    "Employees": {
      "14": {
        "name": "john",
        "age": 12,
        "activity": {
          "Count": 3502,
          "RatingValue": 5
        }
      },
      "17": {
        "name": "smith",
        "age": 23,
        "activity": {
          "Count": 232,
          "RatingValue": 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

js was written to retrieve the nested document and stored in array

```
var result = [];

db.details.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var Employees = doc.Includes.Employees;
    if (Employees) {
        for (var key in Employees) {
            var Employee = Employees[key];
            var item = [];
            item.push(key);
            item.push(Employee.name);
            item.push(Employee.age);
            item.push(Employee.activity.Count);
            item.push(Employee.activity.RatingValue);
            result.push(item.join(","));
        }
    }
});

print(result);
```

How can we store the output of array in csv with 2 rows because the data contains 2 rows by using mongoexport. In csv output must be

14,john,12,3502,5

17,smith,23,232,5

Comment: It works fine, you just have a typo: `var Employees = doc.Includes.Empoyees;`. Empoyees -> Employees

Comment: It was a mistake. Getting the output, dont know how to store in csv

Comment: How do you want to store it? You need to copy-paste the result or something

Comment: 14,john,12,3502,5

17,smith,23,232,5

it must be in individial columns i.e 14 in 1st column of 1st row,john in 2nd column so on.. 17 in 1st column of 2nd row..

Answer (score 0):

```
var csv=""; //this is the output file
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){//loop through output
    csv+=result[i]+"\n"; //append the text and a newline
}
window.open('data:text/csv;' + (window.btoa?'base64,'+btoa(csv):csv)); //open in a new window, chrome will automatically download since it is a csv.
```

Comment: Getting a error : Reference error window is not defined

Comment: Are you not using a browser?

Comment: Might be useful to mention in question. Remove the last line from my code and print the `csv` variable or save it to file somehow.

Comment: You can just print/console.log `csv` and then save the output from the cli.

Answer (score 0):

Change that final `print(result);` to the following:

```
print(result.join("\n"));
```

Then call your script and direct the output to a CSV file like so:

```
mongo --quiet "full-path-to-script.js" > "full-path-to-output.csv"
```

Note: The `--quiet` arg suppresses the standard Mongo header output (shell version and initial database).

I created a *details* collection, and added your JSON document to it, and then running the modified script resulted in the following CSV file content:

```
14,john,12,3502,5
17,smith,23,232,5
```

If you want a CSV header row as well, see my nearly identical answer to your nearly identical question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26310323/3212415