# Retrieve the values from array and store it in csv file using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, csv

This is input json file. Javascript code is written to iterate using MongoDB.

```
{
  "Includes": {
    "Employees": {
      "14": {
        "name": "john",
        "age": 12,
        "activity": {
          "Count": 3502,
          "RatingValue": 5
        }
      },
      "17": {
        "name": "smith",
        "age": 23,
        "activity": {
          "Count": 232,
          "RatingValue": 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Javascript function

```
var result = [];

db.details.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var Employees = doc.Includes.Employees;
    if (Employees) {
        for (var key in Employees) {
            var Employee = Employees[key];
            var item = [];
            item.push(key);
            item.push(Employee.name);
            item.push(Employee.age);
            item.push(Employee.activity.Count);
            item.push(Employee.activity.RatingValue);
            result.push(item.join(","));
        }
    }
});

print(result);
```

I want the output to be written to csv file in 3 rows with 5 columns, each column containing a value in this pattern

Id name age count RatingValue

14 john age 3502 5

17 smith 23 232 5

Answer (score 1):

Change that final `print(result);` to the following:

```
print("Id,name,age,count,RatingValue");
print(result.join("\n"));
```

Note: The first line is just for the column headers; the second line prints each employee result on a separate line.

Then call your script and direct the output to a CSV file like so:

```
mongo --quiet "full-path-to-script.js" > "full-path-to-output.csv"
```

Note: The `--quiet` arg suppresses the standard Mongo header output (shell version and initial database).

I created a *details* collection, and added your JSON document to it, and then running the modified script resulted in the following CSV file content:

```
Id,name,age,count,RatingValue
14,john,12,3502,5
17,smith,23,232,5
```